# what's the purpose of parallel RL circuit on mains recifier?

Tags: power, ac, mains

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frySog.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hi, I was reading a datasheet for DC1744A which is a demo board of LT3799 and this is the rectifying circuit of the board in their datasheet.

I am not sure the purpose of RL parallel circuit before the bridge rectifier
and also why they used the choke inductor (L3) after the rectifier not before. (if it is just a choke inductor of course)

The circuit drives a transformer with high frequency FET switch.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Together with C1 they form a filter. The resistors provide damping.

Comment: What is the 68F supposed to be?

Comment: looking at the original design... its 68nF not 68F F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the FCC or some regulatory committee requires that any EMI generated by a switching power supply be filtered so that it does not back-feed into the AC power lines. Hence the reason why L1 and L2 have substantial inductance. 3.3 mH is a lot of inductance, a brick-wall filter to block HF noise.

The parallel resistors help prevent the L1 and L2 cores from DC and LF  saturation, in which they would behave like a short circuit. Remember they also have to handle the 50/60 HZ current passing through them to feed the power supply. To a 3.3 mH inductor 50/60 HZ passes right through them almost as easy as DC current.

As for L3 it offers the first barrier to the extreme switching noise produced by a SMPS type supply. I am used to seeing common mode inductors at this location but a single ended filter is good enough, since L1 and L2 filter out any remaining noise.

Not shown in the image are the large value capacitors by the MOSFET switch and transformer.

**NOTE: I should point out that this design is atypical of SMPS design. No common mode filters and large 3.3 mH inductors with rather small value capacitors suggest the designer was just throwing parts together, or had SEVERE EXTERNAL noise to contend with. I do NOT recommend this design for SMPS supplies.**

Comment: thank you sir! you saved my day! At the first look it looked like a high pass filter with C1 and was wondering for a day why would they want to pass high frequency on mains. Your explanation cleared it. :D

Comment: L3 will predominantly be there to assist in power quality. The intent of the circuit is PFC and there is a nice little caveat with PFC which is a "stiff DClink". The creation of a 2nd order DClink filter improves the characteristics and also facilitates continuous DClink current.  L1, L2 ... probably EMI

Comment: @JonRB you should expand that into an answer for us.

Comment: I think your reasoning on the resistors is wrong, a 10K parallel resistor will have negligible impact on DC or low frequency current flow. I expect the real reason for them is to limit the voltage that develops if the mains supply is suddenly disconnected.

Comment: This is not a good design. Normally there would be CM chokes in use.

Comment: @PeterGreen. I agree with you, and JonRB has some insight as well. I added a 'NOTE' section to clear up my standing on this. The design borders on the irrational.

Answer (score 1):

I believe these two filters were intended to smooth the fast rise times present on the AC source voltage, probably to prevent disturbing the SMPS on each half cycle.  Thus the two, 2-pole filters from AC in to DC out.

The LT3799 is a flyback SMPS controller, but it's intended specifically to drive LEDs.  One of its features is the ability to be powered from a phase controlled voltage source (triac dimmer).  The DC1744A board was designed to demonstrate this among other features.  Triggering the triac at 90 and 270 degrees (worst case) subjects the input to a step of around 165V.  It's this step that I believe the filters are trying to tame (my opinion...I didn't design the demo board!).

The two 10k and the 750 ohm resistors I believe are as Tony Stewart pointed out: they lower the Q so that the input step doesn't cause severe ringing.

Another feature of this IC is active power factor correction.  For this reason, I don't believe the R-L-C components under discussion are intended to correct power factor.

Answer (score 0):

### I do NOT see this as a good design, with what is shown so far.

### Edit

Inspite of other answers and comments my [simulation](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%200%201378614.6781719956%0Ac%20224%20176%20224%20240%200%203.3e-8%200%0Ar%20464%20176%20464%20240%200%2010000%0AO%20400%20176%20416%20128%200%0Ag%20224%20240%20192%20240%200%0A170%2096%20128%2096%2080%203%2020%201000%205%200.1%0Al%2096%20128%20160%20128%200%200.0033%200%0Ar%2096%20144%20160%20144%200%2010000%0Aw%2096%20128%2096%20144%200%0Aw%20160%20128%20160%20144%200%0Aw%20192%20128%20208%20128%200%0Aw%20160%20144%20160%20160%200%0Aw%20224%20160%20224%20176%200%0Aw%20160%20160%20160%20176%200%0Ar%20160%20176%20224%20176%200%2010000%0Al%20160%20160%20224%20160%200%200.0033%200%0Al%20224%20176%20288%20176%200%200.0033%200%0Ac%20288%20176%20288%20240%200%203.3e-8%200%0Aw%20336%20176%20400%20176%200%0Aw%20224%20240%20288%20240%200%0Aw%20336%20240%20400%20240%200%0Ac%20336%20176%20336%20208%200%206.8e-8%200%0Ar%20336%20208%20336%20240%200%20750%0Aw%20288%20176%20336%20176%200%0Aw%20288%20240%20336%20240%200%0Aw%20400%20176%20464%20176%200%0Aw%20400%20240%20464%20240%200%0Ao%204%2016%200%2034%205%200.00009765625%200%20-1%20in%0Ao%202%2016%200%2034%202.5%200.00009765625%201%20-1%20out%0A) supports my design intuition. The 780R+58nF was a bandaid to fix the resonance with a damper on Q, R7/R8 still do nothing , a Pi filter is far better and this card never got FCC approved.

### My opinion stands, you can make your own design choices.

[image]

### It is adequate for Demo purposes but both a DM and CM Pi filter is best on front end.

R7, R8 do nothing except when there is no load with a reduction of resonant peaks.  The 3.3mH is < 1 Ohm so 10K does nothing substantial.

R8+L2 does nothing except doubles the impdeance of L1 and increases component count.

C1 must be chosen for a switcher rate of >50kHz otherwise it degrades the noise performance with feedback noise if the SMPS in the 20kHz range as this adds a high Q (>20dB) tank resonance near 20kHz but if > 50kHz it creates a 4th order LPF, with 5 reactive elements which is suboptimal.

A far better design is to use **a Pi filter** or CLC Common Mode choke on the front end.  This will reduce egress and ingress noise by more than 30dB. This means L1 L2 might look almost the same but use a common core and raise the CM impedance of both Line,Neutral relative to 3.3nF shunt caps on BOTH sides of the CM L of same value to offer an impedance ratio on the same value parts at 100kHz of > 30dB. Higher inductance or switching rate would result in even more attenuation of conducted EMI.

The R8 (750) C2 (68F) values shown have dubious values which must be incorrect.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for your answer.  C2 should be 68nF. The circuit was from DC1744A board which is a demo board for LT3799 (offline flyback LED driver from linear tech). They also have DC1775A and DC1595A which are different demo boards for the same chip. Only on DC1774A they have different rectifier configuration and I was wondering why. (I've noticed that the transformer that the circuit drives has higher inductance on DC1774A and my guess is to protect from inductive noise?) http://www.analog.com/en/products/power-management/power-control/offline-controllers-pfc/lt3799.html#product-overview

Answer (score 0):

Given the optimal dampening resistor for an LC resonator is sqrt(L / C) to produce Q of 1?, compute sqrt(3.3 milliHenry / 0.068uF) and you get

Rdamp = sqrt(50,000) or 2.2 * 100 =  220 ohms,

thus not quite the "optimal" dampening value, but close.